# How to show full filename under recent files in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: ssms, ssms-18

In SQL Server Management Studio (v18.11), selecting "File | Recent Files", the paths and files are always truncated.

Is there a setting somewhere to change this?

[image: Screenshot of recent files list from SMSS]